# How to append to different parts of array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

I want to append values to array but want to separate when the index is 0 or 1.
For example,

index=np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])

new_values = np.array([5,7,9,4,6,3,5,2,9,5])

array=[]

Here I want to run through the index array and create a new array (called 'array') that will receive new values and group them when the index is 0 or 1.
I should get an output something like this,

array = ([0: 5,9,6,5,9 ; 1: 7,4,3,2,5])

I tried using dictionaries but I guess it didn't work.

How should I do this ?

Comment: Hi fribeiro98, welcome to Stackoverflow. You said that using dicts did not work, can you share your code for that?

Comment: Hi @user5305519. Thanks. My code is much more than this... The only way I could make it was having an output like    array = ([0: 5, 1:7, 0:9 , 1:4 , 0:6, 1:3 , ...]). But I guess thats not what I really want, beacause I should be able to separate in groups when is 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a dictionary and then fill it with a zip of the two arrays, like this:

```
d = dict()
for k,v in zip(index, new_values):
    d[k] = d[k]+[v] if k in d else []
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary to solve this problem. we will insert more than one values to a key.
first we will create an array of sets to store the values related to the key.

```
s = []
for i in range(len(new_values)):
    s.append((index[i],new_values[i]))
print(s)
```

not we will have something like this
s = [(0, 5), (1, 7), (0, 9), (1, 4), (0, 6), (1, 3), (0, 5), (1, 2), (0, 9), (1, 5)]

now

```
data_dict = {}
for x in s:
    data_dict.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])
print(data_dict)
```

output :-
{0: [5, 9, 6, 5, 9], 1: [7, 4, 3, 2, 5]}